# Why did my virus get lost?

Tags: ingress

Recently I've used a virus and lost it. It didn't affect the targeted portal and it went away from my inventory. Why and how did it happen? Was that a system glitch? Did someone else experience something like this before?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use a virus on a recently flipped (in the last hour) portal your virus will be consumed without a warning. You'll only get a message after using the virus telling you that the targeted portal is immune to the process.

This from a formal Ingress post :

> Portals now have a temporary 1 hour immunity to ADA Refactor and
>   JARVIS Virus weapons after a Refactor or Virus has been deployed. If
>   immune, Agents should see: "Failed. Portal Temporarily Immune."
>
> This is important: Failed attempts to use an ADA Refactor or JARVIS
>   Virus weapon will consume the Refactor and Virus, removing it from
>   your inventory.

https://plus.googleapis.com/+Ingress/posts/U6TfcW5KuS3

Comment: The same thing will happen if you don't have enough XM.

Comment: Without enough XM, my virus item didn't get used.